# what will do after icon broke suddenly in appbar?

Tags: flutter

I am developing a flutter app where appbar icon broke suddenly without any reason. Try to fix but nothing has been found yet.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TbbD.png%60)

```
AppBar(   
  actions: [
    GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {},
      child: SvgPicture.asset(
      iconSearch,
      color: VisuColors.white,
      ),
    ),
  ]
)
```

Comment: Can you provide the code of the appbar section?

Comment: Can you provide some part of code? Or Explain briefly

Comment: can you check that 'iconSearch' properly points to the 'svg' file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the image and code that you provide, things that come to my mind are:

1- Try to give width and height to SvgPicture.asset like this:

```
SvgPicture.asset(
  iconSearch,
  color: VisuColors.white,
  width: 15,
  height: 15,
),
```

2- Check the color that you gave to SvgPicture.asset, maybe it has something related to the color.

3- If these 2 solutions didn't solve your problem, check your SVG file and try to use another SVG file to see if the problem is with the file that you use. Because sometimes, the SVG files may be broken (size, color, formatting etc.).